# Big O notation for .forEach with .find

Tags: javascript, typescript, big-o

What is the big O notation for the following code?

```
    _data.validatorInfo.result.validators.forEach((_validator) => {
        let del = {
            delegation: _data.delegations.result.delegation_responses.find(
                res => res.delegation.validator_address === _validator.operator_address
            ),
            validator: _validator,
            rewards: _data.totalRewards.result.rewards.find(
                re => re.validator_address === _validator.operator_address
            )
        }
        result.delegations.push(del);
    })
```

Since it has a `.forEach` and two `.find()` operations nested, can I assume it is O(N^3)?

Comment: `find`s are not nested, the cost the two finds adds, not multiplies. Also a case can be made for the cost being linear, if the length of `validators` is limited by some hard limit (as is often the case for collections named "validators").

Answer (score 2):

You go through all `validators` (V), for each of them going through `delegation_responses` (P) and `rewards` (W) until a certain element is found, which on average means to go through half of the array .

This would give you `V * (P + W)/2`. Big O ignores constants factors (sets them to 1), so that gives you `O(V * (P + W))`. And at that point, you can start arguing:

- If P and W are very small compared to V (like orders of magnitude), you would argue that they behave like constants and only slightly scale the driving factor V, and you deal with effectively linear complexity `O(N)`, where N is the number of validators.
- If V is very small (again, orders of magnitude) compared to P and/or W, you would get `O(N)` or `O(N + M)`, where N and M are number of  responses/rewards, again arguing that V behaves like a constant.
- If they are all about the same size (or you cannot make assumptions about their size), you get `O(N * 2N)`, which is `O(N²)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your complexity is

`O(N*(M+Q))`, where

- N is `_data.validatorInfo.result.validators.length`
- M is `_data.delegations.result.delegation_responses.length` and
- Q is `_data.totalRewards.result.rewards.length`

You can assume that this

- is quadric if N ~ M+Q
- linear if N >> M + Q

Comment: If N is much larger than M or Q, why would that give you quadratic complexity? Doesn't quadratic complexity imply that they are all about the same size, i.e `O(N*(N+N)) = O(2N²) = O(N²)` ?

Comment: Yes you are right, I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than answering your question directly, I want to point out that performance can be improved very easily. A common way to do this would be to use a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) ([`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) to find the items you're looking for.

```
const delegations = new Map();
_data.delegations.result.delegation_responses.forEach((res) => {
  delegations.set(res.delegation.validator_address, res);
});

const rewards = new Map();
_data.totalRewards.result.rewards.forEach((re) => {
  rewards.set(re.validator_address, re);
});

_data.validatorInfo.result.validators.forEach((_validator) => {
  result.delegations.push({
    delegation: delegations.get(_validator.operator_address),
    validator: _validator,
    rewards: rewards.get(_validator.operator_address),
  });
});
```

Using the same letters as [the answer of Radu Diță](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75897029/3982562)

> - N is `_data.validatorInfo.result.validators.length`
> - M is `_data.delegations.result.delegation_responses.length` and
> - Q is `_data.totalRewards.result.rewards.length`

This improved version would result in complexity `O(N+M+Q)`.

---

You might be able to use

```
result.delegations = _data.validatorInfo.result.validators.map(...);
```

if your scenario allows for it.